# map/reduce function on json objects in couchdb

Tags: json, mapreduce, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I have a couple of documents in my couchdb database which all are like:

```
{
"_id":"1234567890",
"name": [
  "category1": 5,
  "category2": 8
]
}
```

I want to have a map function which gives me "category1" as key and 5 as value.
I just can't separate "category" and 5.

I tried the following:

```
function(doc){
    if(doc.name){
        doc.name.forEach(function(sth) {
            emit(sth, null); 
        });
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can help me find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mind that:

- CouchDB function `emit()` takes two parameters, first is a key (eg. `"category1"`), second is a value (eg. `5`). See the [view API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views) documented in the CouchDB wiki.
- `[key:val, ...]` is not correct JSON field syntax, did you mean list of single field records (`[{"key1": val1}, {"key2": val2}, ...]`) or single multi-field record (`{"key1": val1, "key2": val2, ...}`)?
- In case of `"name": [{ "category1": 5}, {"category2": 8 }]` argument of `forEach` continuation is `{"category1": 5}`, and you should get somehow `"category1"` and `5` separately (`forEach()` or `for (var key in sth) {}` once more??).
- In case of `"name": { "category1": 5, "category2": 8 }`, remember the JS object (`{"field": val, ...}`) does not have `forEach` method, array (`[val1, val2, ...]`) prototype does.

Assuming you meant `"name": { "category1": 5, "category2": 8 }` as the name, consider trying the following `map`:

```
function (data) {
  if (date.name) {
    for (var sth in name) {
      emit(sth, name[sth]);
    }
  }
}
```

If you are JavaScript beginer, try writing proper code in console first. You can use the one found in the web-browser (Firefox, Chrome have build-in, I advise FireBug addon for Firefox). Good luck!